# How to run analytics on Paraquet files on Non Hadoop environment

Tags: parquet

We are generating Parquet files , using apache Nifi  in a non hadoop environment. We need to run analytics on Parquet files.

Apart from using apache frameworks like Hive , Spark etc. Do we have any open source BI or a reporting tool which can read Parquet files , or is there any other work around for this . In our environment we have Jasper Reporting tool.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily process Parquet files in Python:

- To read/write Parquet files, you can use [pyarrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html) or [fastparquet](https://fastparquet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html).
- To analyze the data, you can use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) (which can even [read](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_parquet.html)/[write](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet) Parquet itself using one of the implemention mentioned in the previous item behind the scenes).
- To get a nice interactive data exploration environment, you can use [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org/).

All of these work in a non-Hadoop environment.